# Laravel - Same section used in different layout

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have 2 layouts as shown below:

Layout A

```
<html>
  <body>
    <section>
      Hello
    </section>
    This is 1st
    @yield('content')
  </body>
</html>
```

Layout B

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <section>
      Hello
    </section>
    This is 2nd
    @yield('content')
  </body>
</html>
```

Layout A and B both have same section.
Anything I can do to keep the code DRY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

In resources/views/ create a layouts/ directory, and within that create a file called "main.blade.php".

```
<html>
  <body>
    <section>
    Hello
    </section>
    @yield('title')
    @yield('content')
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in each of your two views above you would use :

```
@extends('layouts/main')
@section('title')
    This is 1st / This is 2nd (as the case may be)
@stop
@section('content')
    Content goes here
@stop
```

**Option 2**

Use includes - in resources/views/ create an includes/ directory, and within that create section.blade.php with the content :

```
<section>
  Hello
</section>
```

Then in your two views above :

```
<html>
  <body>
    @include('includes.section')
    This is 1st / This is 2nd (as the case may be)
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Option 2 is best suited for my case. Thanks alot!

Comment: No problem. When you get into things a bit deeper, look into Components in Blade (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components) as it's the same principle as above, but gives you more flexibility.